# Closing connection when event stack is empty

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm somewhat new to node, and so far I love it, but maybe I'm running into a case of it being a hammer when I need a wrench.

I've got a bunch of data in text files, and I need to load these files into a database - very simple in a normal imperative language. I want to write idiomatic node for this, so would rather use async fs calls (`fs.readdir` and `fs.readFile` rather than `fs.readdirSync` and `fs.readFileSync`). However, how do I know when all of those operations are done, so then (and only then) it's safe to close the DB connection?

In short (in pseudo-code):

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  fs.readDir(path, function(err, files) {
    for file in files {
      if (interesting(file)) {
        fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
          doc = turnDataIntoDocument(data);
          db.collection('foo').insert(doc);
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // This is the part that won't work right:
  db.close()
});
```

Obviously, the `db.close()` could happen at any time, probably before all the files are processed, or usually before the directory is even fully-read.

I know there are libraries for dealing with control flow, but I feel like I should understand how to do this at a more fundamental level rather than depending on a library for something so simple - don't close the connection until I'm done with it.

Comment: Actually, a promise library is the proper way to handle this, and is not an unnecessary abstraction.  Basically, you just need to track when everything is resolved.  A simple way is to push a bunch of state objects on an array and track when they're all gone... but that's all your promise library is going to do anyway.  Look at Bluebird.

Comment: I was thinking that tracking an array of state seems a bit unwieldy. I would have to add additional state to know that I've added all the state to be tracked to the queue - turtles all the way down.

Comment: If you're not using promises, the simplest way is to just keep a count of number of operations started and number of operations completed and if the completion callback for the database insert, when all are done, the counts will match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple counter should work in this case:

```
function doInserts(cb) {
  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    fs.readDir(path, function(err, files) {
      var count = files.length;
      if (count === 0) {
        db.close();
        return cb();
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (interesting(file)) {
          fs.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
            doc = turnDataIntoDocument(data);
            db.collection('foo').insert(doc);
            if (--count === 0) {
              db.close();
              cb();
            }
          });
        } else if (--count === 0) {
          db.close();
          cb();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the example. Think I'll just use synchronous I/O for this. While it's a "simple" counter, maintaining this over a lifetime is less than simple.